how to define fixed header in Tk.grid ( grid(10x5)
I am creating a tkinter grid with 10 columns and 5 rows, including an input textbox. I need to know how to create a fixed header and assign a title to the header. Any suggestions would be appreciated
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=5)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky="news", column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

grid.Label(root, text='Title-1').grid(row=0, column=0)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-2').grid(row=0, column=1)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-3').grid(row=0, column=2)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-4').grid(row=0, column=3)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-5').grid(row=0, column=4)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-6').grid(row=0, column=5)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-7').grid(row=0, column=6)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-8').grid(row=0, column=7)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-9').grid(row=0, column=8)
grid.Label(root, text='Title-10').grid(row=0, column=9)


x=1
#example values
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(5):
        text = Entry(frame)
        text.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")

frame.columnconfigure(tuple(range(10)), weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(tuple(range(5)), weight=1)

root.mainloop()

grid.Label(root, text='Title-1').grid(row=0, column=0)


Did you try to run this as-is? Because it throws an exception. the Frame object named grid has no attribute Label. Which means grid.Label doesn't work. If what you want is for the Labels to be children of the Frame widget, do this instead: Label(grid, text='Title-1').grid(row=0, column=0). I would also advise against naming your Frame "grid" as this is confusing at best and can break things at worst.

Here's a minimal example that I believe accomplishes what you're looking for.
I'll leave figuring out how to reference the Entry widgets to you since that wasn't mentioned.
A grid of Entry widgets gets inserted into a Frame along with a row of title Labels whose text (and quantity) is determined by the items in the titles list.
The number of columns is determined by the number of title strings in the titles list.
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

titles = [
    'Title-1',
    'Title-2',
    'Title-3',
    'Title-4',
    'Title-5',
    'Title-6',
    'Title-7',
    'Title-8',
    'Title-9',
    'Title-10',
]

for column, title in enumerate(titles):
    # add column header labels
    tk.Label(frame, text=title).grid(row=0, column=column)

    for row in range(5):  # add 5 rows of Entry widgets
        text = tk.Entry(frame)
        # row here is offset by +1 because the titles are using row 0
        text.grid(column=column, row=row + 1)

root.mainloop()


thank you sir /--------Kindly provide guidance on how to store the user input data from this grid into a pandas dataframe and save it as a CSV file. Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

If this answer worked for you, please click the check mark button to mark it as "Accepted" so others know this question has been answered. If you have other questions, you'll have to ask them separately and demonstrate your attempt to solve the problem with a [mre]


I am creating a tkinter grid with 10 columns and 5 rows, including an
input textbox.

You can downsize the code:
Snippet:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=5)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")


for i in range(1, 11):
    label = Label(frame, text=f'Title-{i}')
    label.grid(column=i, row=0, sticky="news") 
    for x in range(5):
        text = Entry(frame)              
        text.grid(column=i, row=x+1, sticky="news")
                         
root.mainloop() 

Screenshot:


Do you know that you have created ten sets of labels put in same row 0? Create one set of labels inside the outer for loop instead.

@ acw1668. Thank. I didn't realize it.
